# How can I install openjdk-7-jdk on lucid 10.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, java

I'm currently using JDK 6 on a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server.

Since Oracle will not allow JDK 6 in Ubuntu repos now, it looks like OpenJDK 7 is the best alternative https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-security-announce/2012-January/001554.html

I noticed OpenJDK 7 available on 11.10 as a package, but is there a backport package to lucid 10.04 LTS?

I found this one https://launchpad.net/~openjdk but it is one year out of date.

Comment: Alternatively, to install oracle jdk 7, this ppa repo works: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: you can now manually download and install JDK from Oracle's site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get Sun Java 6 from http://blog.flexion.org/2012/01/16/install-sun-java-6-jre-jdk-from-deb-packages/ but make sure to read the comments as there may be updates from the developer himself.
This may be the best option for a few reasons:
**1.** Ortang's suggestion of using the OpenJDK PPA has old versions of OpenJDK and is not recommended. I couldn't even get OpenJDK 7 to install on my Lucid box even though it said it was supported.
**2.** The Canonical Parters repository will be not be updated in the future due to the change in Oracle's policies so do not pull the Java from it. Simply changing your sources.list to Oneiric will not help for older releases.
Of course if you need Sun Java 7, try http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html as previously suggested. I have not tested it, but the WebUpd8 guys are pretty reliable.

Comment: The webupd8 script did not work for me on Lucid and caused some weird issues when I tried to uninstall it. This guide to installing Oracle Java got me there though: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7

Comment: @nick-long: the webupd8 team had to do an update recently, I wonder if you used the old version or the new one (I have not tried either, so I cannot advise) : http://ppa.webupd8.org/post/20061796964/oracle-java7-installer-package-update

Comment: I tried it on 29th March 2012 on a Lucid server

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/etc/apt/sources.list` find

```
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
```

and uncomment the last 2 lines (as shown). Execute `sudo apt-get update`

than type `sudo apt-get install sun` and hit 'tab' button...see if that helps.

Comment: The tab works, but everytime I try to install something it hits a dependency. Is there a set of steps to install this easy. It cant be this crazy.

Comment: I don't get your question. The package manager should be able to resolve all dependencies and install them automatically. Also I think the question's title have changed, from how to install Sun Java to how to install OpenJDK... what do you want to install?

Comment: This is a very bad idea - installing packages from different versions can lead you to dependency hell. I think the best idea is just to upgrade distribution versions.

Comment: what different versions are you talking about?