# Installing openjdk-7-jre on ubuntu 10.04 - Package openjdk-7-jre has no installation candidate

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to install openjdk-7 on my ubuntu but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-7-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package openjdk-7-jre has no installation candidate
```

I suppose I'm missing some repos or something like that but I was unable to find any reference where and what.

Comment: Might be a good question for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Openjdk-7-jre is not in normal repos for Ubuntu 10.04/Lucid. Here is a question about the same problem, the solution is to use webupd8 package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914679/how-can-i-install-openjdk-7-jdk-on-lucid-10-04-lts

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recently had to install Java 7 on CentOS, openSUSE and Ubuntu, and after much fretting and research, finally settled on this, which works on all three flavors:

- Ignore (and uninstall) any JREs or JDKs bundled with / shipped with your distribution. They are more trouble than they're worth, and always way behind the latest updates.
- Download JRE 7 (or JDK 7 if you want to develop) from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html.

  - For the JRE, get jre-xxx-linux-x64.tar.gz if you have a 64-bit machine or jre-xxx-linux-i586.tar.gz if 32-bit. Don't bother with the RPMs.
  - For the JDK, get jdk-xxx-linux-x64.tar.gz if you have a 64-bit machine or jdk-xxx-linux-i586.tar.gz if 32-bit.
- Perform the following as root or using sudo:

  - # tar -xzvf jdk-xxx-linux-x64.tar.gz (or whichever one you downloaded)
  - # mkdir /usr/java
  - # mv jdkx.x.x_xx /usr/java (or, if JRE, this will be the extracted JRE directory)
  - # ln -s /usr/java/jdkx.x.x_xx /usr/java/jdkx
  - # ln -s /usr/java/jdkx /usr/java/latest
  - # ln -s /usr/java/latest /usr/java/default
  - # ln -s /usr/java/default/bin/java /usr/bin/java
  - # ln -s /usr/java/default/bin/javac /usr/bin/javac
  - # ln -s /usr/java/default/bin/javah /usr/bin/javah
  - # ln -s /usr/java/default/bin/javadoc /usr/bin/javadoc
  - # ln -s /usr/java/default/bin/javaws /usr/bin/javaws

Obviously, you'll have to fill in some blanks here, but you should get the picture. As a working example, here is my installation (note that for my purposes I needed both the 64-bit AND 32-bit versions of both the Java 7 AND Java 6 JDKs, so there's a lot):

```
# ls -al /usr/java/
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Sep  2 11:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Aug  9 22:14 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16 Aug 26 20:05 default -> /usr/java/latest
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Sep  2 10:52 jdk1.6.0_35
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Sep  2 10:52 jdk1.6.0_35-32
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Sep  2 10:52 jdk1.7.0_07
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Sep  2 10:52 jdk1.7.0_07-32
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   11 Sep  2 10:54 jdk6 -> jdk1.6.0_35
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   14 Sep  2 10:54 jdk6-32 -> jdk1.6.0_35-32
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   11 Sep  2 10:54 jdk7 -> jdk1.7.0_07
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   14 Sep  2 10:54 jdk7-32 -> jdk1.7.0_07-32
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    4 Sep  2 10:55 latest -> jdk7
# ls -al /usr/bin/java*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Aug 26 20:05 /usr/bin/java -> /usr/java/default/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Aug 26 20:05 /usr/bin/javac -> /usr/java/default/bin/javac
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Aug 26 20:05 /usr/bin/javadoc -> /usr/java/default/bin/javadoc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Aug 26 20:07 /usr/bin/javah -> /usr/java/default/bin/javah
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Aug 26 20:05 /usr/bin/javaws -> /usr/java/default/bin/javaws
# java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Also important: because of Oracle's new stringent requirements about agreeing to their terms every time you want to download Java, you can't download Java with something like wget anymore. It must be downloaded via a browser. If your Linux machine is GUI-less and/or you connect to it via SSH, you will need to download the files onto your local machine, then use something like scp to copy the files onto the Linux machine.

Comment: Can you explain why you have that /default/ folder? Not only do I not see that locally, I am not sure why it is there. Thank you.

Comment: I think you skip a lot of these steps if you use 'update-java-alternatives' command in the place of setting all of those symlinks by hand.   Once you manually set all the symlinks for the first time on one Java instance, you can switch ALL the symlinks with a single 'update-java-alternatives' command.

Answer (score 4):

on ubuntu lucid 64-bit, I needed to add this link to the chain:

```
ln -s /usr/java/latest /usr/java/default
```

Answer (score 2):

The way Oracle is becoming restrictive about Java having an alternative is just good. I think openjdk is pretty nice. Installing it on debian systems like Ubuntu is painless. Please use apt-get like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Update is required if your apt-get cache/metadata are not updated with repositories latest changes that include openjdk-7. Logically installation of pacakge openjdk-7-jre should also work then unless your distribution is not very old.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk-7-jre it's only available via oniric and up.

Comment: Yes, available via oneiric not oniric. What is wrong?

Comment: The poster is running Lucid not Oneiric which is a previous version. In the Debian world is is recommended to never mix packages from different versions as it can cause dependencies conflict.